# How to change translate yii file (messages) path?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I have a project with a few Yii-applications in it. And i want to use one messages (translate) file for some applications, how can i change config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path to messages folder is defined by [basePath](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGettextMessageSource#basePath-detail) property of [CGetTextMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGettextMessageSource#basePath-detail) in Yii. Default value for this property is "protected/messages". It can be changed by putting something like following in your main.php config file:

```
components' => array(
    'messages'=>array('basePath'=>'yourPath'),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read this Special Topic on Internationalization: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

Have a look at this for configuration options:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/59/

Comment: i don't need to read this huge articles, i just wanted to know how to change config